# sftp ls - change the last mod time format to always show year and time

Tags: sftp, ibm-midrange

I've a remote sever where I need to get a list of files, along with their last mod info, from a folder.  The only way to connect to this remote server is via sftp.  I know I can use the ls -l option to obtain those info.  The only problem that I'm having with is the date/time format of the last mod info.  It seems to work like unix style ls -l command, where, depending on the last mod date, it something does not show the last mod year or time.  In qsh, I can use the ls -lT option to have it always show the year and time.  But this T option does not seems to be supported in sftp.  Is there no way to have sftp ls command to always show the last mod year and time?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't able to use `ssh` as well?  `sftp` runs on top of `ssh` so its pretty unusual for someone to allow `sftp` without also allowing direct `ssh` access.

Comment: The server belongs to a bank.  It failed my connection when I try ssh.

Comment: What `sftp` is that? What does your question have to do with IBM-midrange?

Comment: @Martin I execute the sftp from the qshell from a IBM i5.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IBM i5. Do you know what `sftp` is that? Is that OpenSSH `sftp` (build for IBM i5)? Or is that some proprietary client?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The IBM i goes by a lot of names (AS/400, System i, i5, etc) but its been around for something like 30 years now.  The ibm-midrange tag is the proper tag for this question.

Comment: Yes, it is openSSH.

Comment: @Player1st I didn't question that. I was asking how is it related. It's not clear from the question if OP is connecting **to or from** IBM machine.

Comment: @HockChaiLim What version?

Comment: @HockChaiLim Unfortunately, I think you may be out of luck.  I believe `sftp` on the i runs under the PASE environment which as you stated uses the AIX (unix style) `ls` command.  Normally, you'd use `stat` to get the modification time that you are asking for but it doesn't look like that is supported in `PASE` yet.  If you had `ssh`, you could go use the `qsh` command from the `PASE` environment and run the `qsh ls` command that way but I don't believe that works for `sftp`.  The best I can give you is to use `ls -lt` and it will always give you the year in the date.

Comment: @Martin > ssh -V                                   
  OpenSSH_6.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

Comment: @MartinPrikryl My apologies.  I did assume he was trying to log into an IBM i system but you are correct in that if he is trying to log into something else, he may have other options.

Comment: @HockChaiLim As requested by MartinPrikryl, can you clarify whether you are logging into an IBM i machine or logging in from an IBM i machine?

Comment: I'm logging in from the IBM i.  I don't what type of machine the remote server is.  So, when I do a ls -l, is the format of the result depending on the server or from the client?  I was thinking that it is depending on the client, no?

Comment: Much like with ssh, the commands run on the server and not the client.  Clients can take the data from the server and tweak with it to improve the display but the fundamental SFTP commands run on the server and return you the results.  All that said, if you are logging into a remote server that is not an IBM i, give `stat` a try.  It may very well be supported.

Comment: @Player1st No, that's not true with SFTP. The client can format the listing. How else would GUI SFTP client present information that's otherwise not available in what you see in `ls` command output?

Comment: @HockChaiLim I've thought that newer versions of OpenSSH have switches to force full format of the timestamp. Though I was wrong. So there's no way to show a full timestamp with OpenSSH SFTP client. You would have to use a different client (or an SFTP library in any scripting language available for IBM i - like Python or Perl or PHP).

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I'll do a bit more research on that front.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes that's true however no client can format data that isn't returned from the SFTP server.  My understanding is that the data returned by SFTP is determined by the protocol specs.  The protocol specs also support the implementation of `stat` which gives this extra information but if the client and server don't support it, you cannot get the data.  The formatting of that data is still left up to the client.

Comment: @Player1st Sure. But timestamps are returned by the server. So they can be displayed by the client in whatever format the client wants.